# pGina MySQL auth fails when hashed

Tags: mysql, authentication

I have a remote desktop machine that runs an application for remote users, who are authenticated via pGINA against a MySQL database that pGINA created.  When a user registers, a webserver adds an entry for their account to the **`users`** table, and when they RDP in it signs them in.  This works fine when users' passwords are stored in plaintext, however when I hash the password before adding it to the database and indicate as much in the **`hash_method`** column, pGINA fails to authenticate the user.  I have even tried hashing passwords in openSSL and adding the entry by hand and invariably the plaintext entries work while those with hashed passwords do not.  I would love to hear any ideas on what could be happening because at this point I have none.  I've tried capitalization, and double checked that it is set to hexadecimal.